# Taylor series expansion of $(2+3x)^6$

Tags: calculus, functions

The question is

> Find the first 4 terms of de taylor series expansion of $(2+3x)^6$

Is it possible to standard series of $(1+x)^a = 1 + ax + \frac{a(a-1)}{2~!}x^2 +\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{3~!}x^3$ ... or do I have to use another method?

Thanks in advance and a nice evening!

Comment: yes, use that. What you you do to adapt your  (2+3x) to this (1+x) pattern ?

Comment: To be more explicit, $(2+3x)^6 = 2^6(1+3x/2)^6$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

$$(x+y)^n= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 1):

what you have is correct. but you can use the standard binomial series/pascal triangle to expand 
$$(2+3x)^6 = 2^6 + {6 \choose 1}  2^{5}(3x)^1 + {6 \choose 2}  2^{4}(3x)^2  + \ldots$$

Comment: Yes, this solution is valid. Still, the guy proposed a totally valid way too, and it would be nice to say him so first ! ;-)